# How do I fix a cygwin_exception when running the "git log" command?

Tags: git

I have recently installed Git on my PC (Windows 7 64 bit) and I am trying out some simple commands.

I have made a couple of commits using the "git commit" command.

Now I am running the "git log --oneline" command in hopes of seeing a list of my commits. However, I am receiving the following error message:

```
0 [main] less 45176 cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to less.exe.stackdump
```

I am hoping someone can point me in the right direction of what might be causing this exception.

Thank you!

Comment: Which version of Git did you install?  Git for Windows?

Comment: @EdwardThomson, yes; git version 2.15.0.windows.1